# Constrained maximization problem

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, convex-optimization

I need help with the following optimization problem

$$
\max\;\alpha\ln(x(1-y^2))+(1-\alpha)\ln(z)
$$
where the maximization is with respect to $x,y,z$, subject to
\begin{align}
\alpha x+(1-\alpha)z&=C_1\\
\alpha y\sqrt{x(x+\gamma)}-\alpha x&=C_2
\end{align}
where $0\leq\alpha\leq1$, $\gamma>0$, and $x,z\geq0$, and $|y|\leq1$.

Generally, one can substitute the constraints in the objective function and maximize with respect to one parameter. The problem is that in this way things become algebraically complicated, and I believe that there is a simple solution.

Thank you

Comment: Why don't you solve set of three equations - derivatives of αln(x(1−y2))+(1−α)ln(z) by dx, dy and dz, asuming α and γ constant? Than add your two conditional equations (about C1 and C2). Then solve set of five with five unknowns (it would be system of linear equations, use matrixes for them).

Comment: @oroboros There are only three unknowns $x,y,z$. I edited the question to make this clearer.

Answer (score 2):

You should use [Lagrange multipliers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier), write out the Lagrangian, differentiate it w.r.t. $x,y$ and $z$ and set them to zero.

Your Lagrangian for this problem would be:

$$\mathcal{L}(x,y,z)=\alpha ln(x(1-y^2))+(1-\alpha)ln(z)+\lambda_1(\alpha x+(1-\alpha)z-C_1)+\lambda_2(\alpha y\sqrt{x(x+\gamma)}-\alpha x-C_2)$$

You need to set $\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial z}=0$ and eliminate $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ to get your optimal $x^*$, $y^*$ and $z^*$.

Comment: Of curse, but, as I said (or meant) obtaining solutions to these equation is tedious. The question is whether there is another simple (maybe tricky) way to solve this problem, or, these equations.

Comment: @user39097: I do not see any trick, but $\lambda_1=-0.5$ it seems from calculations. $\alpha$ also gets eliminated, so perhaps it is not as daunting as you think it is.

Comment: Interesting.. Can you please provide the analysis? I get another complicated solutions. THANK YOU!

Comment: I tried again, and I get complicated non-linear equations. In particular, how did you get that $\lambda_1 = -0.5$?

Comment: Sorry, I meant $\lambda_1=-1/z$ for interior $\alpha$. You get that from the third Lagrangian condition.

Comment: With that I agree (unfortunately).

Answer (score 1):

Use the second constraint to eliminate $y$ and the first constraint to eliminate $z$ from the expression that you want to maximize. The result is a function of $x$, in fact a linear combination of three terms of the form $\log(A_k x+B_k)$.

The complete picture also depends on the values of $C_1$ and $C_2$, about which we have been told nothing.